# Image segmentation on android

Tags: java, android, image

I am developing an application on the android platform. The app basically needs to capture an image using the camera(already done) and then analyse the captured image to see where does one color ends and the next one starts (assuming the image would always have 2 or 3 dominant colors and would be really simple). Any ideas?

P.S. I have already tried OpenCV, but there are two problems: 1. The library needs to be installed previously on your phone for your app to work and I can't have that since it will be a commercial app (I am not sure about this dependency though) 2. Secondly, the min-sdk for my app is android 2.2 and for OpenCV it's 2.3

Comment: When it comes to computer vision, all relevant information of the problem domain is valuable. Therefore, please be more specific in what you want to achieve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV, while a good general purpose library, is just a collection of utilities that deal with pixels.  If the license and min SDK are issues, write it yourself.  Segmentation is a matter of choosing a starting x,y location within the image and traversing in each direction until a pixel is encountered that meets or exceeds your threshold for "different".  Use a stack to keep account of where you stepped in x and y and then backtrack by popping indices off the stack and follow another direction when you get back to where you were. Push indices onto the stack when you step in either x or y.
It's not difficult, just rather tedious, but that's why people wrote libraries to do this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I have just started using OpenCv and the problem you mentioned (installing library) was one of the major issues faced by me too. However I found a solution  to this problem by declaring the OpenCv initialization as static. When you make the initialization static then there is no need for the pre-installation of those libraries.

Gud Luck!

Answer (score 0):

To do something like that you'll need to do image processing. A very popular library for C++/Java which can certainly handle this is [OpenCV](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/).

Comment: Yes I have tried that, but there are two problems:
1. The library needs to be installed previously on your phone for your app to work and I can't have that since it will be a commercial app (I am not sure about this dependency though)
2. Secondly, the min-sdk for my app is android 2.2 and for OpenCV it's 2.3

Comment: Okay, then I don't know what the other options are. I would advise you to put stuff you've already tried in your original question though, avoids useless replies like mine in this instance :-).

Comment: OpenCV is BSD licensed, so you may grab the source to the functionality you need and incorporate it into your app, adapting it if need be to support Froyo. Your main other option is to roll your own image recognition.